# Pass image from one view to another view by preparesegue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimage, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to pass image from one viewcontroller to another . I have tried all available solutions on stackoverflow , still i am struggling with the same. How can i pass uiimage through preparesegue ??

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"filter"]) {
    FilterViewController *cvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    UIImage *image = imageView.image;
    cvc.desktopview.image = image;
    NSLog(@"segue");
}
```

}

Comment: This is a right way to do that. Is your NSLog called? How do you know the image was not passed?

Comment: Check that the @"filter" is really the name of the segue ;)

Comment: Where you are accessing image in filterViewController

Comment: Try to access it in viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `FilterViewController.h`

add a uiimage there `@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImage *dvImage;`

Go to `FilterViewController.m`

Synthesize it `@synthesize dvImage;`

Go to the code Where you are calling the `FilterViewController`

```
FilterViewController *cvc = [segue destinationViewController];
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
cvc.setDvImage = image;
NSLog(@"segue");
```

and then in `viewDidLoad` set `self.desktopview.image = dvImage;`

Don't forgot to check the **segue identifier**

Hope this helps

Comment: use synthesize or _dvImage

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because it isn't ready yet.

```
cvc.desktopview.image = image;
```

Instead you need to store it in a `UIImage` property and use it in `viewDidLoad` method of your destination view controller.

Something like this in `prepareForSegue`

```
cvc.image = image;
```

and in the view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.desktopview.image = image;


}
```

Edit:

You need this at your view controller's header file.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage * image;
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer, cvc is viewcontroller , how can you set .image. Dude i am novice in ios development . please help me out .

Answer (score 1):

`ViewDidLoad`  is called only after ALL outlets are loaded, so never try to set outlet/views value in prepare segue method, as `viewDidLoad` will be called after prepare segue method. Now you can do one that create an UIImage property in `filterViewController` and set its value. and In `viewDidLoad` method set it to specfic `imageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Optimized way

```
 [segue.destinationViewController setAnotherImage:yourImage];
```

Another view controller

```
-(void)setAnotherImage:(UIImage *)happiness
{
    //get your image here
}
```